# Cannot run exported Processing application on Ubuntu

Tags: processing, ubuntu-14.04

I have a processing 3 sketch that runs correctly via Processing. After exporting as a Linux application, it creates the application.linux32 and application.linux64. I set the script to execute and then run with ./AppName.

The error returned is "unable to run sketch without a display".

There should be a "display" as the sketch has some images and animation.